# Prevent modal div from going off-screen

Tags: css

[Link](http://cometconcept.webflow.io/)

The modal is centered in the middle of the screen (top slightly off-center to account for browser UI etc).

If you resize the browser window to have a height smaller than the div's, its goes off-screen. What method could I use to make it stop at the top and then enable the user to scroll the element to see it all?

```
.modal {
   position: absolute;
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   margin-top: -200px;
   margin-left: -200px;
   top: 47%;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Weird, I have no issues with that - Firefox 38

Comment: @bodi0 what do you see when you resize the browser window so the height of it is small? For me you can only see the center of the div and the top and bottom bit of it go off-screen. Makes sense with the position absolute and top/left centering.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a `max-height` rule to the existing media queries? e.g., `@media (max-height:400px) { .modal { margin-top:0; top:0; } }`

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't even realise you could do max-height media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use media css option:

```
@media (max-height: 400px) {
 .login{
   overflow-y: scroll !important;
   margin: 0 auto !important;
   position: static !important;
  }
}
```